# Are the semidirect products of two finite cyclic groups all isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, semidirect-product

Going over an exercise in Dummit and Foote (5.5 #12) and got to a point where I have to show the 3 non-abelian groups of order 20. I was thinking about it more and it seems like the group $C_5 \times C_4$ is isomorphic to all the semi-direct products between $C_5$ and $C_4$. I think this would be because all the homomorphisms $\phi : C_4 \rightarrow Aut(C_5)$ have images which are conjugates of each other so there's really just the one semidirect product and the trivial semidirect product (the direct product). But the non-trivial semidirect products are still isomorphic to a direct product with an order 5 cyclic group in one spot and an order 4 cyclic group in the other. Is this true? Is there some intuition or angle that I'm missing here?

Comment: $C_5\times C_4$ is abelian; how can it be "isomorphic to all the semi-direct products between $C_5$ and $C_3$"? Especially if there *are* nonabelian groups of order $20$, and all of them must be semi-direct products? Since $\mathrm{Aut}(C_5)$ has order $4$ and is cyclic, there are three possible images for $\phi$: it can be all of $\mathrm{Aut}(C_5)$; or the image can be trivial; or the image can be the unique subgroup of order $2$. None of those can be conjugate to another.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am still learning these concepts. Perhaps answers to these two questions will help me understand your comment.

1.) Is $C_5 \times C_4$ isomorphic to $Z_{10} \times Z_2$ or $Z_{20}$? 

2.) Is $Z_5 \times Z_4$ the same (under isomorphism) as $C_5 \times C_4$

Comment: It seems like maybe the semidirect products of any two groups are only isomorphic if the normal group is cyclic and two homomorphisms that define the left action are conjugates, then those semidirect products are isomorphic?

Comment: $Z_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, so $Z_5$ and $C_5$ are just two names of the same thing. To answer your first question: what is the order of the element $(x,y)$ in $C_5\times C_4$, where $x$ generates $C_5$ and $y$ generates $C_4$? It is false that “the semidirect products of two groups are only isomorphic if the normal subgroup is cyclic and the two homomorphisms that define the action are conjugates”. For example, both the trivial action and the nontrivial action by conjugation yield isomorphic semidirect products $A_5\rtimes A_5$.